# Django, ModelChoiceField() and initial value

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using something like this:

```
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=...)
```

How can I make my form show the a value as selected?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you want to set the default initial value you should be defining [`initial`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) like other form fields except you [set it to the id instead](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg36019.html).

Say you've got `field1` like this:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = MyModel.objects.all() )
```

then you need to set initial when you create your form like this:

```
form = YourForm(initial = {'field1': instance_of_mymodel.pk })
```

rather than:

```
form = YourForm(initial = {'field1': instance_of_mymodel })
```

I'm also assuming you've defined `__unicode__` for your models so this displays correctly.

Comment: Don't know what the version was at the time of this writing, but this question is now a bit out-dated. In Django 1.5, as of writing, both of these methods would work.

Comment: any idea why I get `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument field1`

Answer (score 30):

You can just use

```
 field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., initial=0)
```

to make the first value selected etc. It's more generic way, then the other answer.

Comment: What version of Django does this work for? It doesn't seem to work for me in version 1.8.

Comment: I have verified from the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.11/django/forms/models.py#L1127-L1130) and test it out myself that this is working for `django>=1.8`. I believe this should work for all version including `>=1.4`

Comment: @Raffi yes, the [link in my comment above](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.11/django/forms/models.py#L1127-L1130) is pointing to the parameter of `ModelChoiceField.__init__(..., initial,...)` for Django=1.8.11.

Answer (score 11):

The times they have changed:

The default initial value can now be set by defining `initial` like other form fields <del>except you set it to the id instead</del>.

Now this will suffice:

```
form = YourForm(initial = {'field1': instance_of_mymodel })
```

Though both still work.

Comment: Please specify what version of Django you're running now that the "times have changed." Changed for some out there might be upgrade to 1.2...

Answer (score 5):

The code

```
form = YourForm(initial = {'field1': instance_of_mymodel.pk })
```

and

```
form = YourForm(initial = {'field1': instance_of_mymodel })
```

or initial field directly following:

```
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., initial=0)
```

All work.

The first two ways will override the final way.

Answer (score 3):

```
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.all(), empty_label="Selected value")
```

It's as simple as that....!

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add this answer after stumbling on this question. I know it works on Django 3.2, at least.
If you have some calculated value in the `__init__` method, you can do this to set the initial value at instantiation as well:

```py
def __init__(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    # super call, etc.
    self.do_something(value)
    self.fields['field'].initial = value
```

If the form does multiple things with `value`, it's a bit more DRY to pass it only once instead of redundantly with the `initial` kwarg in instantiation.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this as well:

```
form = YourForm(initial = {'field1': pk })
```

if you are parsing your primary key through a query string or via an ajax call no need for an instance, the query set has already handled that for your drop down, the pk indexes the state you want