# Django ModelChoiceField

Tags: django

I'm new with Python and Django. I'd like to use combo box with ModelChoiceField like below.

```
school = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=School.objects.all())
```

The school object have a 'id', 'Name', 'Domain' fields but when I render the form in the html it show like below.

```html
<label for="id_school">School:</label> 
<select id="id_school" name="school">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="3">School object</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to make the text from 'Name' field and make the first row to be selected. 
Also it would be great if you have any reference site some one like me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shows `School object` because that's how the `School` objects are rendered. If you don't specify anything in `School` model then that's how django would render objects.

What you need to do is to define `__str__` method for `School` model. The `__str__()` method is defined as:

> The `__str__()` method is called whenever you call `str()` on an
>   object. Django uses `str(obj)` in a number of places. Most notably, to
>   display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted
>   into a template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always
>   return a nice, human-readable representation of the model from the
>   `__str__()` method.

```
class School(models.Model):
    def __str__(self)
        return self.name
```

Django doc about [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str).

Comment: In python 2, can use unicode instead of str : 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.name)

Comment: For those who copy paste, this answer has a missing semicolon, def __str__(self):  ...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the first object selected by default then you should so something like that in your form model:

```
school = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=School.objects.all(), initial=0)
```

If you want to set the initial value from an instance of your model you can check accepted answer here [SO accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336900/django-modelchoicefield-and-initial-value)