# how I get selected value from options using ModelChoiceField(queryset=...) in django

Tags: django

```
class Model_Neural_form(forms.ModelForm):
    allMod = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model_Neural.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Model_Neural
        fields = ["nom_mod", "modl"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model_Neural_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['allMod'].label = ''
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, ModelChoiceField() and initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336900/django-modelchoicefield-and-initial-value)

Comment: No this doesn't help me, here is my view s.py the code doesn't give e any error but it doens't give me the selected value I don't know why : if request.method == 'POST': form = Model_Neural_form(request.POST, auto_id=True) if form.is_valid(): print (form.cleaned_data['allMod'])

Comment: How you try this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default initial value you should be defining initial like other form fields.

You need to set initial when you create your form like this:

```
allMod = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    initial=instance.pk if instance else None,
    queryset=Model_Neural.objects.all()
)
```